# Fill_Parent и Match_Parent

Tags: android, xml

В чем разница между `match_parent` и `fill_parent`?

Comment: ни в чем. fill_parent является устаревшим свойством, но по сути является тем же match_parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

match_parent = fill_parent. Первое свойство нужно использовать в новых проектах, второе свойство считается устаревшим и пока оставлено в целях совместимости.

Comment: fill_parent следует указывать, если требуется совместимость с API8 и ниже, в остальных случаях - match_parent, действие их одинаково и они имеют одно значение константы -1

Answer (score 0):

Fill_parent это устаревший и на новых прошивках его не  видит ,чаще  всего полностью зачеркивает .Fill_parent=Match_parent оба дают расширение до краев экрана.если         android:layout_width="match_parent" то здесь от одного края экрана до другого края
в ширину        android:layout_height="match_parent" то в высоту

Comment: Не до краев экрана, а заполнить все пространство родительского контейнера - этот контейнер может и не занимать весь экран